# EC2 fstab and the best time to bind a directory

Tags: mount, amazon-web-services, fstab

I have a server on aws that I needed to upgrade ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04 to get the newer version of php.  I ran several tests to see if my setup would upgrade and all appeared ok.  However, I ended up bricking the box and then next box as well.  I spent the last several days working through a new fresh install of 12.04 instead of the old system.  This is to document the gotcha and ask a question regarding the best time to bind directories.

The box kept bricking when I improperly tried to mount drives that had not mounted previously.  In the stock install of ubuntu on aws it creates an ephemeral drive.

Below is the fstab.  As you can see the /dev/xvdb mounts with nobootwait and causes all of the following mounts to fail because the other mount points are not there.  As it fails they give a prompt

```
The disk drive for /mnt/www/webfiles1 is not ready yet or not present
Continue to wait; or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

Since this is on a aws cloud I can't interact with the prompt and it just hangs.  Adding nobootwait to the other mount points did not solve the problem.  It was only after commenting out the /dev/xvdb line and creating the mount points on the root drive that everything worked as expected.

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0
/dev/xvdb      /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0       2

# Web Files on external drives
UUID=5103351c-7303-4add-838f-5595ba5c105f /mnt/www/webfiles1 ext3 defaults 0 0  
UUID=730faa81-669d-4263-8687-114b112d4488 /mnt/www/webfiles2 ext3 defaults 0 0  
UUID=c7807090-2edd-4cab-bbfe-9815a92fc809 /mnt/www/webfiles3 ext3 defaults 0 0  

# Jailed web developers
/mnt/www/webfiles1/website1.com/www /home/user1/home/user1/www none bind 0 0
/mnt/www/webfiles2/website2.com/www /home/user2/home/user2/www none bind 0 0
```

The question is regarding the mounting of the jailed web developers.  Is mounting their jailed directories in fstab the best place to do it or should it be done elsewhere?

Mark